# How to mask bits in C

Tags: c

I need to get the tag bits, set index bits and block offset bits. I have the user enter the information. S = number of sets, E = number of lines per set, B = block size, m = address bits. Then I calculate the set index bits, block offset and tag bits. Then I need to mask bits to get the index bits, block offset bits and tag bits from the user input. This is where my problems are occurring, I'm not sure if I'm masking the bits correctly. For example, when I do, S = 4, E = 1, B = 8, m = 8, which equals to index bits = 2, offset bits = 3, and tag bits = 3. Then the user enters 30 for example, then my outputs come out to offset = 0, tag = 6 and index = 3 which is wrong. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```
int m;
/*fundamental parameters of the cache */
double S;
int E;
double B;

int t;

printf("Enter for S: ");
scanf("%lf", &S);

printf("Enter for E: ");
scanf("%d", &E);

printf("Enter for B: ");
scanf("%lf", &B);

printf("Enter for m: ");
scanf("%d", &m);

int s;
int b;

/*bits for the set, index bits*/
s = Log2(S);

/*b is the offset number*/
b = Log2(B);

/*The remaining number for the tag after the set and offset*/
t = m - (s + b);
printf("%d\n", s);
printf("%d\n", b);
printf("%d\n", t);

int address = 0;
printf("Enter the value: ");
scanf("%d",&address);

unsigned long offset = (address >> 0) & ((1 << b) -1 );
unsigned long tag = (address >> (s+b)) & ((1 << t) - 1);
unsigned long index = (address >> b) & ((1 << s) -1);


printf("%lu\n", tag);
printf("%lu\n", offset);
printf("%lu\n", index);

return 0;
}



double Log2(double n)
{
  return log(n) / log(2);
}
```

Comment: please show a layout of your bit patterns in these numbers.  bits this through that are index, bits this through that are offset, etc.

Comment: When formulating a solution, it is often quite helpful to express the solution in an example.  Would you please append the statement of the problem as "for this input data, the output should be X"?

Comment: Hmm, "S = number of sets" --> perhaps next time use `double number_of_sets;` instead and the explanatory note is not needed.

Comment: `int s; s = Log2(S);` is prone to failure (not get the expected answer) due to slight computational limitations.  Suggest `s = roundl(Log2(S));` or the like.

Comment: Since one is trying to mask an `unsigned long`, be sure computation is done with `unsigned long` math: `(1 << b)` --> `(1UL << b)`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Next time I'll make my post more clearer, sorry about that

Comment: @wallyk For example, 00110000 is 30 in binary, I want tag to be 001, 00 for set, then 000 for offset.

Comment: Will masking my bits get me those binaries that i want? I am trying to make a cache simulator.